What am I doing wrong here?
braedendg@penguin:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version (8.0~repack-4).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 8.0~repack-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
braedendg@penguin:~$ ^C
braedendg@penguin:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
braedendg@penguin:~$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
braedendg@penguin:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version (8.0~repack-4).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 8.0~repack-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
braedendg@penguin:~$ ^C
braedendg@penguin:~$ ^[[200~apt --fix-broken install~
-bash: $'\E[200~apt': command not found
braedendg@penguin:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
braedendg@penguin:~$ 

It keeps asking me if I'm root but I don't know what that means, nor how to fix it.

Become root (the system management userid) by prefacing your command with sudo, e.g. sudo apt install wine. Your life will be easier if you resolve the problems with one command (in this case, install the dependencies) before rushing to the next. Unix/Linux is a powerful tool, and will let you make powerful errors. Only learning how it works, and what the commands do, can make it safer.

What exactly are you trying to do? Presumably install wine but are following some guide? Which one? Linux distro (and release/version)? Is your system fully updated? Very likely not... You shouldn't be trying to install stuff if you have apt errors. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Hi, your command apt --fix-broken install should be prefixed by sudo that's why it request you if you are root.

@admstg please don't post answers in comments.

@ChanganAuto please don't add the Linux tag to questions unless they are asking about the kernel itself. The tag shouldn't be used just because a question is being asked by a Linux user.

@terdon I didn't. It was there originally when I edited. But good to know it has a strict usage as it should be.

Oh wow, @ChanganAuto, you're absolutely right! For some reason, your suggested edit had the Linux tag highlighted in green as though you had added it and the two tags you did add were shown in red, making me think you removed them. So I thought you were adding a bad tag and removing two good ones, so I rejected the edit. I'm sorry, it was a good edit and I should have accepted it, no idea why it appeared that way.

You are (correctly) using sudo for the first phase, but when it says it needs further actions (ie when it says you should try apt --fix-broken install) you should also prefix that with sudo, as it touches things used by more than your own user.
Ie, instead of apt --fix-broken install (which would only work if logged in as the root user) use sudo apt --fix-broken install
